# In which template file is a node title supposed to be?

Tags: theming, 8

I have to add a *Title* field to each content type to ensure a title appears on the node view.

This makes me wonder: Maybe I'm missing the *title* variable in my implementation of page.twig.html or something, but I don't see a *title* variable anywhere in the default [page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!seven!templates!page.html.twig/8.2.x).

1. In which template should my title variable be displaying?
2. What should the code in the template look like to display the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Page title is now a block**
>
> The page title is now provided by a block so it can be easily moved
>   without editing the page template.
>
> The markup for the page title can be edited in page-title.html.twig,
>   and template_preprocess_page_title() can be used in conjunction with
>   the template

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2568563

Comment: Thanks - I must have accidentally moved it to 'disabled' in block layout...so that fixed it.